# Close bootstrap drop down menu after a item is clicked

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

So in my bootstrap 3.3.6 I have a menu that includes links.

In smaller sizes the menu becomes a dropdown menu and I want , when a menu item is clicked , the menu to go away.

I guess I can do something like

```
function closeMenu(){
  //? uhm, what?
}

document.getElementByClass ("menuLink").addEventListener("closeMenu",findit,false);
```

but I dont have a clue what to set inside my function, so the dropdown will go back up again

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: if you are asking idea then it can be..use click event after click means as some one will click on menu then use click event again so there will be 2 click and your menu will be close after opening

Comment: @Leothelion Hello. I did not understand why I should "use click event again". Why I have to use the click again ? User clicks the menu button> menu drops > user clicks menu item > redirection and menu closes at the same time. So, I guess one click is enough. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: It should close once an item is clicked: http://bootply.com/5t0sASdQWw

Comment: Great Skelly.. follow his code..your work is done..and m giving workarround..leave that.. thanx skelly

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way.

Inside the div with the links, I set a controller and `ng-click` for every link.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="navCtrl" >                  
                        <li><a ng-click="menuLinkClicked()" href="#/"> Home </a></li>                
                        <li><a ng-click="menuLinkClicked()" href="#jake"> Jake</a></li>                
                        <li><a ng-click="menuLinkClicked()" href="#amir"> Amir</a></li>    

</ul>
```

and in my controller

```
app.controller('navCtrl',['$scope',
    function ($scope) {  
        $scope.menuLinkClicked = function () {                        
            document.getElementById("navbar").className="navbar-collapse collapse";
        };        
    }
]);
```

`navbar` is the id of the menu that collapses in smaller screens. I use `document.getElementById("navbar")` to get it and then change its class to make it dissappear.